# ThreadPoolExecutor for different task

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

bellow is the default PicassoExecutorService.java , it just do request bitmap from net (and from http cache,if loaded before ) . say , if have 100 task , and 95 is loaded in cache and 5 is from net , if the 5 in the first 5 of the queue , the 95 image will never show when the 5 picture be loaded . so , i want to change PicassoExecutorService.java , i want to know is it possible to create a new thread in ExecutorService to just do disk cache fetch job ? should i create a new queue？　i　have not so much exprience with java thread coding , so i need your help , thaks .

```
class PicassoExecutorService extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
  private static final int DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT = 3;

  PicassoExecutorService() {
    super(DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT, DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), new Utils.PicassoThreadFactory());
  }

  void adjustThreadCount(NetworkInfo info) {
    if (info == null || !info.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
      setThreadCount(DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT);
      return;
    }
    switch (info.getType()) {
      case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI:
      case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX:
      case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET:
        setThreadCount(4);
        break;
      case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE:
        switch (info.getSubtype()) {
          case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:  // 4G
          case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
          case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
            setThreadCount(3);
            break;
          case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS: // 3G
          case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
          case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
          case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
          case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
            setThreadCount(2);
            break;
          case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS: // 2G
          case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
            setThreadCount(1);
            break;
          default:
            setThreadCount(DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT);
        }
        break;
      default:
        setThreadCount(DEFAULT_THREAD_COUNT);
    }
  }

  private void setThreadCount(int threadCount) {
    setCorePoolSize(threadCount);
    setMaximumPoolSize(threadCount);
  }
}



  static class PicassoThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
      return new PicassoThread(r);
    }
  }

  private static class PicassoThread extends Thread {
    public PicassoThread(Runnable r) {
      super(r);
    }

    @Override public void run() {
      Process.setThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
      super.run();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Both, your `PicassoExecutorService` and your `PicassoThread` are best examples of an anti-pattern: using unnecessary subclassing. You can set both, the thread count of a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and the priority of a thread without creating subclasses of them. The best advice I can give you is, if you are not experienced with java thread coding, don’t limit the number of threads and don’t mess around with thread priorities. Then you don’t have the problem described in your question. In most cases your optimizations are unnecessary, if not even counterproductive.

Comment: thanks @Holger , i think it's good to do the disk cache fetch not in the PicassoExecutorService , but now i have no idea how to check if the image is in disk or not . i will do some research .

Comment: @Holger Well, mike needs somehow to limit the number of simultaneous connections for a mobile device.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev i just want the disk cache image show first and not to be stuck by network-fetch image .

Comment: Yep, I got it. I've updated the answer with a strategy.

Answer (score 2):

The class `PicassoExecutorService` is an implementation of an executor service which adjusts thread count for a connection type. I.e. for 2G it chooses 1 thread because 2G is slow and setting 4 simultaneous threads would exhaust your connection.

The problem you're facing is because some of the not cached jobs get ahead of the cached requests.

Now, if you're able to determine if the job is cached, you just create a separate service or thread for the disk jobs. The thread pool you showed us is a connection thread which limits the resources based on the connection type. It's better not to mix up the concerns and create a separate thread pool for the disk jobs.

If you can't say if the job is cached before trying to fetch it from the internet, I'll update the answer with a strategy, which is quite sophisticated.

**UPDATE**

The strategy.

First you need to get an idea of a disk read timeout on all of your devices. You need 95th percentile timeout value, e.g. the value less than a maximum. So if you have 1ms, 2ms, 1ms, 50ms, 20ms, 3ms, you don't choose 20ms or 50ms. Let it be 3ms for a disk read. Your average (or better median) connection timeout should be much greater - like 100-500ms.

So the idea is to first submit your jobs to a thread pool of like 10-20 threads with this small timeout. Thus it will filter out all the slow jobs.

Next step is to terminate the slow jobs. This depends on whether your connections are interruptible or not. And if not, it's a different question.

After this you just re-submit the slow jobs to the connection thread pool. And that's it.

Comment: i want see the sophisticated strategy , currently i don't know if the job is cached , it's done by Picasso.

Comment: i think 1 thread is ok , like PicassoExecutorService , the thread count for 2G is 1 (for both disk-fetch and net-fetch) . as the file is in disk , i think there will have no timeout , cause we will got the file finally .